# Error: near "VALUE": syntax error

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

```
INSERT INTO "Мой класс"(Ученик,Успеваемость,Характеристика)
   ...> VALUE("Антон Иванов","Ударник","Примерный ученик");
Error: near "VALUE": syntax error
```

Появилась такая ошибка пока мне неизвестная в sqlite3. Сильно не ругайтесь новичок в СУБД.

Comment: Букву S потеряли, должно быть `VALUES`. И не понятно что за знак больше перед ним

Comment: Спасибо!сам затупил(

Comment: @Mike знак больше это похоже просто приглашение для ввода в интерактивной консоли